# Multiple iFrames: block parent page until user finishes his job with the current frame

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

My requirement is to show 3 third party pages using iFrames. I need to show these 3 third party pages, 1st one on click of image, 2nd one on click of anchor where these two are present in the content page holder body portion and 3rd one on the click of anchor in Header party of the page which is in master.

Right now, i'm using 3 iFrames for each one of them.

My Problem is when still one iFrame is open, I'm able to click on the other iFrames which should not be ideally. I mean if one frame is open, the parent page should not be accessible to the user until he finishes save or close the iFrame. Even i tried jQuery blockUI, but the loading message is appearing on the iFrame which is unpleasant for the user to access the iFrame.

1)  I need clarification how to achieve the functionality, only the iFrame which is opened at present is accessible and make the parent page unaccessible until user completes his action on the iFrame opened currently. Blocking the parent page till user finishes his job with opened iFrame.

```
parent.window.$.blockUI(); //but it is making the iFrame visibility hided by the msg
```

Please provide me some feasible solution to achieve the above functionality.

2)  can i use single iFrame and dynamically change the src attribute using javascript? or maintain separate iFrames individually to avoid dilemma in using frame ID's.

Please advice me, i achieved all the functionality with frame except these two things. If these are achieved then the functionality will be perfect without any hassles for the user to access the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery dialog option modal=true solved my first problem. As of now i kept individual frames for the 2nd one..